# Delay setting in jQuery Banner Rotator plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working with an awesome and flexible jQuery banner rotator but I needed to modify it to load the slides from an external source. I got the external source working great and the slideshow loading but I can't seem to get it to recognize the delay setting.

Basically I modified how the plugin initiates so that it loads my external content and then formats it before the slideshow function.

```
// Grabs data from Sphere Photo Gallery and formats the HTML for jQuery Banner Rotator plugin
function sphereSlider(options) {
    $.get("PhotoGallery.aspx.htm",function(data){
        var html = '';
        $(data).find('#pg_summary img').each(function(i){
            var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
            html += "<li>";
            html += "<a href='"+imgsrc+"'><img src='"+imgsrc+"' border=0/></a>";
            html += "<div class='imgCaption'>";
            html += "<h1>"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_title:eq('+i+')').html().replace("&nbsp;","")+"</h1>";
            html += "<a href='"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_title:eq('+i+')').html().replace("&nbsp;","")+"'></a>";
            html += "<div class='slideDesc'>"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_longdescriptor:eq('+i+')').html()+"</div>";
            html += "</div>";
            html += "</li>";
        });
        $('.thumbnails ul').html(html);
        $(".container").wtRotator(options);
    });
}
```

And then in the html I call my function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      sphereSlider({
      width:900,
      height:254,
      thumb_width:24,
        thumb_height:24,
      button_width:24,
      button_height:24,
      button_margin:5,
      auto_start:true,
      delay:5000,
      play_once:false,
      transition:"block.fade",
      transition_speed:800,
      auto_center:true,
      easing:"",
      cpanel_position:"inside",
      cpanel_align:"BR",
      timer_align:"top",
      display_thumbs:false,
      display_dbuttons:false,
      display_playbutton:false,
      display_thumbimg:false,
        display_side_buttons:true,
      display_numbers:false,
      display_timer:true,
      mouseover_select:false,
      mouseover_pause:true,
      cpanel_mouseover:false,
      text_mouseover:false,
      text_effect:"fade",
      text_sync:true,
      tooltip_type:"text",
      shuffle:false,
      block_size:75,
      vert_size:55,
      horz_size:50,
      block_delay:25,
      vstripe_delay:75,
      hstripe_delay:180     
    });
    }
  );
</script>
```

It should work since all other settings are working. It's just the delay time that is not correctly being set. Any help would be appreciated. I have uploaded the full source to http://www.truimage.biz/cc/rotator.zip for troubleshooting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem easily by removing a couple of texts.

Because there are a wrong annotation in "js/jquery.wt-rotator.js".

From :

```
//Line: 1842
//set delay
//this._delay = this._$items[i].data("delay");
```

To :

```
//set delay
this._delay = this._$items[i].data("delay");
```

Comment: I think the original author of the script did that just to make me feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I think the $.each function works assync, so the Slider was created before all of your images was outputed into HTML.

Try using for insted of each:

```
$.get("PhotoGallery.aspx.htm",function(data){
    var lbls=$(data).find('#pg_summary img');
    var html = '';
    for (var i=0; i< lbls.length; i++ ){
        var imgsrc = $(lbls[i]).attr("src");
        html += "<li>";
        html += "<a href='"+imgsrc+"'><img src='"+imgsrc+"' border=0/></a>";
        html += "<div class='imgCaption'>";
        html += "<h1>"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_title:eq('+i+')').html().replace("&nbsp;","")+"</h1>";
        html += "<a href='"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_title:eq('+i+')').html().replace("&nbsp;","")+"'></a>";
        html += "<div class='slideDesc'>"+$(data).find('#pg_summary .pg_longdescriptor:eq('+i+')').html()+"</div>";
        html += "</div>";
        html += "</li>";
    }
    $('.thumbnails ul').html(html);
    $(".container").wtRotator(options);
});
```

Comment: Didn't really change the result. The slideshow seems to ignore the delay setting and correctly sets all other settings. Super bizarre.

Comment: Just an fyi, I localized the images by actually writing the images html directly in there and stripped down the sphereFunction to only have this inside:
`function sphereSlider(options) {
     $(".container").wtRotator(options);
}`

Therefore I think it is calling it in the html
`$(document).ready(function() {
            sphereSlider({options});
        });`